# How to reload google captcha to unchecked using reload frame after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, captcha, simplecaptcha

**I want to reload google captcha after form submit**, I've searched a lot, there are many methods like Recaptcha.reload(); or grecaptcha.reset(); or data-callback and there are some other ways to disable submit button after form submit.

Google designed captcha to make sure we are human, but after checked the box, it won't reload captcha to unchecked.

If we right click on google captcha, there's an option **Reload Frame** that it will unchecked captcha.

Here is my question:

How can I reload google capctha after form submit using the same function as "Reload Frame"

[Right Click Reload Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXKXe.png)

I highly appreciate if anyone will be able to provide a simple JavaScript code that it will work after submit button to reload google captcha to unchecked.

Regards